# Installing R Windows 10

Tags: r, installation

I've been trying to install R from CRAN on Windows 10 for a few days now. I download the execute file from CRAN (R-3.2.3) for 64 bit Windows and install. I cannot find the folder it created anywhere and none of the desktop icons appear. When I try to reinstall, it says R is already installed on the computer. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any installing on Windows but doesn't it ask you where you want to install it? Maybe pay attention to that and see if that folder is created.

Comment: The folder that I specify I want it installed in, whether it's the default or one I choose, is never created but the software insists, upon reinstallation, that it's there. Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The default location is `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3` (or `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO\R-3.2.3` for MS R Open) on Win 10 or it was on the install I just did :).

Failing that, check the registry keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\R-core` (there's both 32 and 64 install paths)

Comment: I didn't know about MS R Open! Thanks! I couldn't figure out the initial problem with the R install I was using but MS R Open installs just fine on my machine! Thanks!

Comment: No problem @MattLivingston glad it helped. Since you're new, just though I'd mention it's customary to vote or accept useful answers http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Comment: I did vote, however, it will not let it be public because I haven't earned enough reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

If you install  R as a windows administrator then R defaults to installing into

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1
```

(though you are given the chance to install into a different folder) , however if you install it as a standard Windows user it gets installed into ...

```
C:\Users\*your_user_name*\Documents\R\R-3.5.1
```